# Separability is not hereditary property

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, separable-spaces

I have to prove that separability is not hereditary property.
If I can prove that every topological space is a subspace of some separable topological space . Then is it enough or not!
Please help!
Thank you in advance

Comment: You should also know that counterexamples need not be terribly pathological. It's true that subspaces of separable metric spaces are separable, but e.g. $\{0,1\}^\mathbb R$ (Tychonlff product topology) is a separable compact Hausdorff space whch has non-separable subspaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, **that would indeed** be enough (and indeed is the right way to approach the problem, in my opinion). In fact there is a very simple way to embed a given topological space in a larger space which is separable:

> Just add a single point, and make that point belong to every (nonempty) open set in the larger space.

Comment: Now that's dense :).